# Find the mass of the thin wire if its linear density is given by $f$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of the thin wire if its linear density is given by $f$.

The wire has the form of a semicircle

$\vec{c}(t) = (a, asin(t), acos(t)), a > 0, 0 \leq t \leq \pi, f(x, y, z) = xyy$

**my attempt**

we know

$M = \int_{C} f(\vec{c}(t))||\vec{c}'(t)|| dt$

$\vec{c}'(t) = (0, ascos(t), -asin(t))$

$||\vec{c}'(t)|| = a$

$f(\vec{c}(t)) = ???$

How do I get above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $f(c(t))$ simply denotes the composition between $f$ and $c$, so that $f(c(t))=a^3\sin^2 t$. Now the mass is given by
$$
M = \int_0^{\pi} a^3\sin^2 t \cdot a\,dt = a^4 \frac{\pi}2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$c(t)$ parametrizes the wire, so the first coordinate of $c(t)$ is $x(t)$, the second coordinate of $c(t)$ is $y(t)$ and the third one is $z(t)$.